# Setting up a new application using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am working to design an application, wherein, we have static and dynamic content.
One way to design is :-
A user will hit CloudFront distribution to access the application (or we can set up Route53 infront of that).
   CloudFront > S3 (for static content)
   CloudFront > API Gateway > Lambda (for dynamic content)

On top of that we don't want to cache dynamic content.
Thus, request for dynamic content will always a miss for CloudFront.

So, is there a way to altogether avoid calling CloudFront for dynamic content.

Reiterating, can i somehow make below possible :-
   CloudFront > S3 (for static content)
   API Gateway > Lambda (for dynamic content)

Comment: What about just callilng the api gateway directly (or setting its own subdomain in Route53), not using cloudfront url for that? APi gateway has its own cache, and also can be set to be Edge Optimized.

Comment: If I enable cache for a stage in API Gateway then all routes through that stage will be cached. Isn't so ?
Though, I don't want to cache index.html.

Is there a recommended way to handle these scenarios ?

Comment: The API gateway cache is only for API gateway, i.e. dynamic content. You don't have to enable it. And for static files, you have cloudfront. You can also exclude some files from it as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-cloudfront-from-caching-files/).

Comment: Understood.
So, how can I configure a system, wherein index.html comes from API Gateway and index.js comes from CloudFront ?